# Why Babel compile 'this' keyword as undefined inside a prototype function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, babeljs

I just started to learn `ES6` so I used `Babel` to compile that code, but when I assign `this` keyword to a variable inside a prototype method it compiled to `undefined`

is this a bug? or problem with my code?

**ES6 Code**

```
function Prefixer(prefix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
}

Prefixer.prototype.prefixArray = arr => {
    let self = this;
    return arr.map((x) => {
        console.log(self.prefix + x);
    });
}

var pre = new Prefixer("Hello ");
pre.prefixArray(['Jeeva', 'Kumar']);
```

**Babel Compiled Code**

```
'use strict';

function Prefixer(prefix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
}

Prefixer.prototype.prefixArray = function (arr) {
    var self = undefined;
    return arr.map(function (x) {
        console.log(self.prefix + x);
    });
};

var pre = new Prefixer("Hello ");
pre.prefixArray(['Jeeva', 'Kumar']);
```

[image: Code Snippet Screenshot]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware that we very much dislike code in images, and prefer to have code we can actually copy and paste, or even execute. Indent code with four spaces to show as code. You can do it automatically by selecting your code visually, then hitting `Ctrl-K` (or `Cmd-K` on Mac).

Comment: Because you're using an arrow function, `this` is inherited from the defining scope. You should **not** use arrow functions for prototype methods

Comment: Oh ok, so there is a limitation with arrow functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Shortly, in arrow function, `this` has no binding.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was caused by the arrow function, I thought the arrow function is just a normal function allow to write less code, but now I got it, it's a totally different from normal function